# Cell formats need to change with changing cell value

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have the following code that I use to apply conditional formatting to a worksheet. The problem is, if I vary the value in `Formula1:=Cells(11,7)` [for example], the formatted data does not reflect the updated change. When I open the Excel's *Conditional Formatting Rules Manager*, the rules do not show a reference to the actual cell, but the value of the cell at the time that I ran the macro. Any thoughts?

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 7 To 13
    Range(Cells(21, i), Cells(118, i)).Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
        Formula1:=Cells(11, i)

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With


    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
        Formula1:=Cells(13, i)

    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
       .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
       .ColorIndex = 6
       .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
Next
```

Comment: You don't need to loop. Check `ModifyAppliesToRange` method like what I did in these posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23752853/2685412) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25320881/2685412). You can also check how I explained it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307005/2685412).

Comment: Does that work for reference values that are unique to each column? For 6 columns it will be 12 rules.

Comment: Seeing your sample code, it should. But again that doesn't answer your actual question. I just thought you might want to consider a simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks I will probably implement that soon, very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something more like `Formula1:="=$G$11"` so:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
        Formula1:="=" & Cells(11, i).Address()
```

Comment: This works and does exactly what I was asking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this to set the Formula1 property.

```
Formula1:="=Cells(11, " & i & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks, that is getting closer, now the output in Excel shows the rule as being based on the Cells(R,C) value. Is there a way to convert it to $A$1 somehow?